# Pass a HTTP request to an internal service in Java/Groovy?

Tags: java, api, rest, http, groovy

A coworker and I are building a small API gateway to allow external access to our team's internal services. We're requesting an endpoints array from each service, which we then expose and handle using [Spark](http://sparkjava.com/). ***Our question is this: what's the best way to pass these HTTP requests to our internal services (which accept HTTP requests and return JSON, usually) and return the response?*** We've been thinking about using Square's [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) to rebuild and resend each request, but that seems pretty hefty.

Here's what we're essentially trying to accomplish with pseudocode:

```
app.get('/dogs', { request, response ->
    response.send(service.httpRequest(request))
})
```

Comment: Not giving you a hard time, but questions posted on stackoverflow should focus on a specific code-based problem and usually include example code for review. A question like yours is probably a better fit on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/). Again, no hassle, but I think you will get a better response on Programmers.

Comment: @SeanMickey when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)